# Ошибка в коде. Recycler View, Camera

Tags: java, android

Есть 1 активность, на ней кнопка, далее открывается камера, после того, закрытие камеры, мы возвращаемся на 1-ую активность, там отправляется запрос на сервер, информация от сервера записывается в SQLite, далее я беру информацию из базы данных и записываю в ArrayList, после того, как я записал array list данные, я создаю адаптер который кушает ArrayList. Ну и собственно обновляется каждый раз.

Но происходит следующая ситуация: открываются активности, потом по нажатию на кнопку, открывается камера, потом возвращение на активность(или кнопкой назад или после сканирования) и все. Карточка не рисуется, при повороте экрана, карточка рисуется. Т.е проблема с отрисовкой. Нужно,чтобы сразу после выхода из камеры рисовалась карточка.

public class BasketActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "just";
private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ProductAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView productRecycler;
private Cursor cursor;
private ProductDbHelper productDbHelper;
private String token;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(productRecycler.getAdapter() == null){
        adapter = new ProductAdapter(productList);
        productRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        //productRecycler.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(productList));
    }else{
        productRecycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basket);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent intentBasket = getIntent();                            //В этой активности нужен токен,для отправки его на сервер и проверки,
    token = intentBasket.getStringExtra("token");    // есть ли данный токен в БД
                                                                  //Нужно подправить скрипт "1", т.к он не проверяет по токену.
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("start", true);

            if (isFirstStart) {
                Intent i = new Intent(BasketActivity.this, MyIntro.class);
                startActivity(i);

                SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
                e.putBoolean("start", false);
                e.apply();
            }
        }
    });

    t.start();


    productRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.product_recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    productRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    productRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);


    productDbHelper = new ProductDbHelper(this);
    db = productDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    cursor = productDbHelper.getInformation(db);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Product product = new Product(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            productList.add(product);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
   /* if(productRecycler.getAdapter() == null){
        adapter = new ProductAdapter(productList);
        productRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        //productRecycler.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(productList));
    }else{
        productRecycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    */

    // productRecycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();


    //adapter = new ProductAdapter(productList);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // productRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            productDbHelper.close();
            new IntentIntegrator(BasketActivity.this).initiateScan();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Scanned");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String barcode = result.getContents();


        new Async().execute(barcode);


    } else {


        Log.d("TAG", "Cancelled scan");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_basket, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId(); //получение id нажатой кнопки в баре

    if (id == R.id.search_product){
        Intent intentProducts = new Intent(BasketActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
        Log.d("MyToken", token);
        intentProducts.putExtra("token",token);
        startActivity(intentProducts);
    }

    if (id == R.id.clear_table) {

        db.delete(ProductInformation.ProductAdd.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        productList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //   productRecycler.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(productList.size(),productList.size());

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


class Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    private String unit;
    private String name;
    private String price;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler response = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet("http://appit.hostenko.com/1.php?sh=" + params[0]);

        try {
            resp = (String) hc.execute(http, response);
            Log.d("DAS", resp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject parsedObject = new JSONObject(result);
            price = parsedObject.getString("cost");
            name = parsedObject.getString("name");
            unit = parsedObject.getString("ed");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ProductDbHelper productDbHelper = new ProductDbHelper(BasketActivity.this);
        db = productDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        productDbHelper.putInformation(name, unit, price, db);
        productDbHelper.close();




    }

}
```

}

Comment: О какой такой карточке-то вы всё время спрашиваете?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну КардВЬю

Comment: А почему у вас только одна `CardView`? Она у вас не в `RecyclerView`?

Comment: В Ресайклвью, все верно.

Comment: Не нашел в коде место, где после записи в БД идет добавление нового элемента в ArrayList. А при повороте экрана "карточка" добавляется из-за того, что происходит переопределение адаптера.

Comment: @NikotinN , разве это не добавление в ArrayList
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Product product = new Product(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
                productList.add(product);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

Comment: Это добавление, но оно происходит только при создании activity, т.е. при создании активити у тебя все элементы добавляются в лист и выводятся. При повороте экрана происходит пересоздание активити, поэтому у тебя всё заполняется как надо. А когда ты в postExecute парсишь ответ , то ты делаешь запись только в базу, а arrayList не обновляешь.

Comment: Почему нельзя сразу читать из БД в список, зачем нужно перекладывать из БД в коллекцию?

Comment: Аааааавтор!!!!!!! Уберите строку `setHasFixedSiE(true);` у `RecyclerView`! Она нужна только тогда когда размер списка фиксирован и в процессе работы приложения не меняет размеры!

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы отдаете адаптеру только в момент инициализации - в методе `onResume()`

Вам нужно создать метод у адаптера - `adapter.setItems(productList)` после чего вызывать `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Ошибка в том, что вы обновили `productList`, но адаптеру новые данные не отдали.

Лучше если вы вынесете инициализацию адаптера в `onCreateView()` и всякий раз когда у вас будут новые данные, вы будете их передавать адаптеру через вызовы `adapter.setItems(productList)` и затем вызывать `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

UPD: еще нашел одну проблему - после получения данных с сервера, в методе `onPostExecute()` нужно обновить ваш `productList` и отдать его адаптеру. об этом говорил Сергей комментарием выше. Поэтому у вас после поворота девайса происходит чтение новых данных с базы - вынести в отдельный метод `reloadInformation()` и вызывать этот метод в методе `onPostExecute()` после записи в базу

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        JSONObject parsedObject = new JSONObject(result);
        price = parsedObject.getString("cost");
        name = parsedObject.getString("name");
        unit = parsedObject.getString("ed");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //ProductDbHelper productDbHelper = new ProductDbHelper(BasketActivity.this);
    db = productDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    productDbHelper.putInformation(name, unit, price, db);
    productDbHelper.close();

    productList.add(new Product(name, unit, price));
    adapter.setItems(productList); // adapter = new Adapter(productList)
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

В `onPostExecute()` добавляйте информацию в `ArrayList`. Я не знаю как выглядит конструктор вашего класса `Product` поэтому оставляю возможность самому дописать

```
productList.add(new Prоduct( ?, ?, ? ));
```

И после этого берете и уведомляете адаптер об изменении данных

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Поправьте, если что-то не так понял, просто код плохо читабелен. Автор, совет дам, даже не пытайтесь пересоздавать адаптер, это самый, что ни на есть **костыль**. Адаптер создаётся один раз и продумывается логика таким образом, чтобы в процессе пользования приложением менялись некие данные, например, лежащие в массиве, при изменении и вызове любого метода `notify...()` у адаптера обновлялись.

Главное все продумать.

**UPD**

Уберите строку

```
productRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true):
```

У вас список поэтому и не меняется. Эта строка является настройкой `RecyclerView`, которая фиксирует размеры списка.